# how to open slide menu on button click in android xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I want to create sliding menu in android in xamarin.forms. I know I can do this with help of MasterDetailPage. But I don't want to use MasterDetailPage. I want a button my page and on click of that button slide menu should open.

Is it possible to open slide menu without help of masterdetailpage in xamarin.forms?

Comment: Your question is a little vague with regards to what your intentions are concerning the MasterDetailPage.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can share? Otherwise it'll be difficult to help you.

Also, it's not 100% clear what issue you're facing exactly, so it might be an idea to restate your problem.

Comment: sounds like he's trying to activate the slide menu with a different button because he's hiding the default button

Comment: Yes Slepz, I want to activate slide menu with different button. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using e.g. an `AbsoluteLayout` as your page Content. Add the slide menu in your layout out of the current view, and on click, animate it into view. It's that simple.